# How to check number of rows in db before inserting

Tags: android, sqlite

Scenario is like
               Before inserting into sqlite db I have to check whether is it reached a particular number, say 10. I know it can be done by using 2 queries for get and insert.

Can it be done in 1 query in android and sqlite

Comment: Would you mind telling the purpose behind doing this ? So that few good solutions could be suggested.

Comment: And what should happen when it has reached 10?

Comment: if it reach 10 say some message

Comment: I just want to limit datas into db to limit db size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Customers (name, age)
SELECT 'MM', 20 WHERE (SELECT count(*) from Customers) < 10;
```

By use this query, we only insert new customer to database when total customers in database < 10

Comment: here how could we know if record is not inserted

Comment: if you want to know record is not inserted or not, you need `using 2 queries for get and insert`

Comment: you want add only unique records or check your insert adds records ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [documentation for INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) you can also insert a result of a select statement. So instead of inserting the values directly, you could assemble a select statement to only return your default values with `coalesce` if and only if a condition for the count yields true.

This is mostly an idea and theoretical approach, but worth trying.

Answer (score -1):

To check how many rows in database, you need to make

> select * from

query and get the cursor object. Cursor object have getCount method  which return you size of cursor, its simply means to show all your records in table.
Cheers!!!

Comment: in question itself I hav told this is not I want